# How to map the word in data frame to integer ID with python-pandas and gensim?

Tags: python, pandas, gensim

Given such a data frame, including the item and corresponding review texts:

```
item_id          review_text
B2JLCNJF16       i was attracted to this...
B0009VEM4U       great snippers...
```

I want to map the top `5000` most frequent word in `review_text`, so the resulting data frame should be like:

```
item_id            review_text
B2JLCNJF16         1  2  3  4  5...
B0009VEM4U         6... #as the word "snippers"  is out of the top 5000 most frequent word
```

Or, a bag-of-word vector is highly preferred:

```
item_id            review_text
B2JLCNJF16         [1,1,1,1,1....]
B0009VEM4U         [0,0,0,0,0,1....]
```

How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
I have tried @ayhan 's answer. Now I have successfully changed the review text to a `doc2bow` form:

```
item_id            review_text
B2JLCNJF16         [(123,2),(130,3),(159,1)...]
B0009VEM4U         [(3,2),(110,2),(121,5)...]
```

It denotes the word of ID `123` has occurred `2` times in that document. Now I'd like to  transfer it to a vector like:

```
[0,0,0,.....,2,0,0,0,....,3,0,0,0,......1...]
        #123rd         130th        159th
```

Do you how to do that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, to get a list of words in every row:

```
df["review_text"] = df["review_text"].map(lambda x: x.split(' '))
```

Now you can pass `df["review_text"]` to gensim's Dictionary:

```
from gensim import corpora
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(df["review_text"])
```

For the 5000 most frequent words, use filter_extremes method:

```
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=1, no_above=1, keep_n=5000)
```

doc2bow method will get you the bag of words representation (word_id, frequency):

```
df["bow"] = df["review_text"].map(dictionary.doc2bow)

0     [(1, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1), (11, 1), (12, 3), (18...
1     [(0, 3), (24, 1), (28, 1), (30, 1), (56, 1), (...
2     [(8, 1), (15, 1), (18, 2), (29, 1), (36, 2), (...
3     [(69, 1), (94, 1), (115, 1), (123, 1), (128, 1...
4     [(2, 1), (18, 4), (26, 1), (32, 1), (55, 1), (...
5     [(6, 1), (18, 1), (30, 1), (61, 1), (71, 1), (...
6     [(0, 5), (13, 1), (18, 6), (31, 1), (42, 1), (...
7     [(0, 10), (5, 1), (18, 1), (35, 1), (43, 1), (...
8     [(0, 24), (1, 4), (4, 2), (7, 1), (10, 1), (14...
9     [(0, 7), (18, 3), (30, 1), (32, 1), (34, 1), (...
10    [(0, 5), (9, 1), (18, 3), (19, 1), (21, 1), (2...
```

After getting the bag of words representation, you can concat the series in each row (probably not very efficient):

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(s).set_index(0) for s in df["bow"]], axis=1).fillna(0).T.set_index(df.index)


    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737
0   0   2   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   10  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8   24  4   0   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   ... 1   1   2   0   1   3   1   0   1   0
9   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
10  5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solution is quite beautiful! But can you please tell me how to transfer the `doc2bow` result to vector? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I leave this question for a week and pick it up again now. I tried your code but the length are still different and all the value are binary: `0` or `1`. Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is really cool! But I wonder whether the index of `df2` is same with `df`?

Comment: so I can merge df and df2 safely?

Comment: But when I look into `df`, there is a word has three occurrence. And when I call `np.amax(df2[0]`, the result is `1.0`

Comment: three occurences means over that document: `(105, 3)`

Comment: hi! I wonder how can i extract the word with a given id after I construct a dictionary as you suggest above? Thanks!