# How to transfer the bag-of-words to a big doc-word-matrix in R?

Tags: r

For a data frame with this form:

```
docId          bow
1              [(3,1),(4,3),(6,1)...]
2              [(1,1),(2,5),(3,1),(6,3)...]
...
```

I wish to generate a big doc-word-matrix with size `d * w` (`d` denotes the number of documents and `w` denotes the number of words):

```
0 0 1 3 0 1 ....
1 5 1 0 0 3.....
....
```

There has been a python solution in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250297/how-to-map-the-word-in-data-frame-to-integer-id-with-python-pandas-and-gensim/36250884?noredirect=1#comment61069474_36250884). I wonder how to do it in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we can extract all the (idx,count) first then format it into the required matrix format as follows:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(stringi)
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(docId=1:2, bow=c("[(3,1),(4,3),(6,1),(10,8)","[(1,1),(2,5),(3,1),(6,3)"))
tuples <- stri_extract_all_words(df$bow)

ans <- rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(tuples, function(x) {
    idx <- stri_split_fixed(x, ",", simplify=TRUE)
    idx <- `dim<-`(as.numeric(idx),dim(idx))
    res <- matrix(0, ncol=max(idx[,1]))
    res[1,idx[,1]] <- idx[,2]
    res
}))
ans[is.na(ans)] <- 0
ans
```